# Understanding Thread Dump of Apache Tomcat 6.0.26

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, tomcat6, threadpool

I made an observation and I would like to fully understand it.

First I regularly take a thread dump and create a summary of the thread states:

```
jstack -l 19498 > dump.txt ; awk '/State: / { print }' < dump.txt  | sort | uniq -c
```

The result of the command above looks like this:

```
 70    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  8    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
  1    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
171    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
```

`RUNNABLE` = actually serving requests of the web application
`TIMED_WAITING` = Quartz Scheduler threads
`WAITING` = idle threads waiting to process upcoming HTTP requests

Example of WAITING thread (all WAITING look like this):

```
"http-80-178" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fa8c0bbe000 nid=0x2e11 in Object.wait() [0x00007fa8aaae9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00007fa8e6b873c8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
        - locked <0x00007fa8e6b873c8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

**Tomcat Configuration**

My Tomcat configuration parameters are using the default values, meaning

`minSpareThreads = 25` (so Tomcat makes sure that there are 25 threads ready for processing
`maxThreads = 200` (200 requests can be processed in parallel without warnings)
`acceptCount = 100` (HTTP Connector can queue up additional 100 requests if all 200 threads are busy)

**Issue**

When I execute the command periodically, I see that the **total number of threads is increasing**. There are no `BLOCKING` threads.

I don't understand why the number of threads is increasing because there are many many threads in the `WAITING` state, ready to process another HTTP request.

I also see the `RUNNABLE` + `WAITING` is constant for a certain amount of time (e.g. 1 hour), but then it increases by 5 or 6 and stays constant again. It seems that the thread pool gets larger and larger until the limit is reached and Tomcat shuts down...

The `TIMED_WAITING` threads are most probably coming from the Quartz Scheduler which runs in the same JVM.

Is my interpretation of the values incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this article](http://papweb.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/understanding-tomcat-executor-thread-pooling/)? Quoting a small chapter:

> Because of the FIFO behaviour of the java ThreadPoolExecutor, each
>   thread will at minimum wait for a new task for “maxIdleTime” before
>   being eligable for closure. Moreover, again because of the FIFO
>   behaviour of the thread pool, for a thread to be closed it’s required
>   that a period of time at least equal to *maxIdleTime* passes without **ANY**
>   request coming in

Comment: Yes, I've found that article. So I wonder why this has been designed like this... A FILO strategy would be much better, no?  
  
However, the last sentence is not clear: "for a thread to be closed it’s required that a period of time at least equal to maxIdleTime passes without ANY request coming in". Does it mean "any request coming in for THIS thread or in general for ANY thread?

Comment: I too agree with this article. Wish had more time to experiment with thread pools myself and try the suggested LIFO/FILO options. From what I understood, he speaks about request to ANY thread. But don't take my word for it - test this and let all us know!